# Import error installing tlslite

Tags: python

I'm trying to install tlslite. After installed the module I've tried to test it and I receive this error:

```
from .checker import Checker
ImportError: No module named checker
```

I've checked on my pip module list and checker is installed... 
Any idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: Sure that dot is meant to be there in front of checker?

Comment: I've tried without dot as well but I receive the same error

Comment: that's weird.. even changing to checkers it says: ImportError: No module named checker

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed tlslite correctly, try this:

```
>>> from tlslite.checker import Checker
```

If that doesn't work, check that tlslite is in your site packages

Answer (score 0):

To work with [tlslite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tlslite/0.4.6) I recommend to use a virtualenv and install TlsLite inside:

```
cd ~/virtualenv/  # <- all my virtualenv are here
virtualenv myvenv
source ~/virtualenv/myvenv/bin/activate
pip install -q -U pip setuptools  # ensure last version
pip install tlslite
```

With that in hand, you can use the `Checker`:

```
$ python

>>> from tlslite.checker import Checker
>>>
```

Et voilà !